# Change text color based on classification - datatable Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, datatable

I have created a data table using React Js. I have a column named Classification. I need to change the colors of a column text based on its classification. Means different colors for each classification.

For instance, Growth classification needs to be in green color, whereas Circular Classification needs to be in red.

```
   const columns = [
{
  name: i18n.t('Stock Symbol'),
  selector: row => row.stockSymbol
},
{
  name: i18n.t('Stock Name'),
  selector: i18n.language == 'en' ? 'stockNameEn' :'stockNameAr'
},
{
  name: i18n.t('Stock Classification'),
  selector: i18n.language == 'en' ? 'stockClassification' :'stockClassificationAr',
  className: 'red'
},
{
  name: i18n.t('Sector') ,
  selector: i18n.language == 'en' ? 'gicsSectorNameEn' :'gicsSectorNameAr'
},
{
  name:  i18n.t('Share Price') ,
  selector: row => row.marketPrice,
  style: row => row.marketPrice > 10 ? {color:'red'} : {color:'green'}
},
{
  name: i18n.t('Market Cap') ,
  selector: row => row.marketValueFormatted,
  className: 'red'
}
```

]

```
<DataTable
      noHeader
        columns={columns}
        data={getFilteredCompanyData}
        highlightOnHover
        className='react-dataTable'
        pagination
        paginationPerPage={10}
        paginationRowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15, 25, 50]}
        paginationComponentOptions={{
        rowsPerPageText: 'Records per page:',
        rangeSeparatorText: 'out of',
        conditionalRowStyles: { conditionalRowStyles }
    }}
    />
```

I tried adding styles and classes into it but nothing worked.

Also tried conditionalRowStyles but didn't work

```
    const conditionalRowStyles = [
  {
    when: row => row.marketPrice > 30,
    style: { color: 'orange' },
  },
  {
    when: row => row.stockClassification == "Growth",
    style: { color: 'green' }
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-data-table-component npm-package you can check :

- https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/api-custom-conditional-formatting--page

Comment: It is better to avoid [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/671985) by providing a self-contained solution in the answer. You can use links for references, acknowledgements, further reading, etc. But the basic solution should be visible in the answer itself.